# Maven packaging - build an environment file?

Tags: java, maven

I use maven to build some java project and compile it to Jar
along with this jar I have some configuration file that is environment specific
Is it possible to have maven create multiple configuration files
given additional "environment files"

configuration file content:

```
server_url={SERVER_URL}
server_port={SERVER_PORT}
```

environment file1 (for dev)

```
SERVER_URL=DEV_SERVER
SERVER_PORT=8080
```

environment file2 (for qa)

```
SERVER_URL=QA_SERVER
SERVER_PORT=8091
```

So the output will be:

```
the_main.jar
config_dev.ini
config_qa.ini
```

**UPDATE**
To clarify, I have multiple files, i want to retain only one foe development for example:

- application.xml
- application.db.ini
- application.config.ini

what I would like is to plant the variables in each one of the files to have something like:

- application_DEV.xml
- application_QA.xml
- application.db_DEV.ini
- application.db_QA.ini
- application.config_DEV.ini
- application.config_QA.ini

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can combine both Maven resources filtering and Maven profiles features to do this.

**[Maven Profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)**

**pom.xml**

```
<project>
  ...
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>DEV</id>
      <properties>
        <config.server>DEV_SERVER</config.server>
        <config.port>8080</config.port>
      </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>QA</id>
      <properties>
        <config.server>QA_SERVER</config.server>
        <config.port>8091</config.port>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  ..
</project>
```

**Run Maven with profiles**

> `-P<profile>`

*DEV*

```
mvn ... -PDEV
```

*QA*

```
MVN ... -PQA
```

**[Filtering with Maven Resources Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)**

**Filtering activation**

```
<project>
  ...
  <name>My Resources Plugin Practice Project</name>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
      ...
    </resources>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

**Configuration file**

```
server_url=${config.server}
server_port=${config.port}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: this is a better approach, but it overwrites the same files, is there a way to clone resource files like  application_DEV.xml   application_QA.xml?

Comment: If you need to keep all the configuration files at the end, I dont think you don't need Maven for this. You just need to define all the configuration files manually.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using `maven-antrun-plugin`.

Firstly you should declare the environment variables you want to write to the files

```
<properties>
   ...    
   <server.dev>DEV_SERVER</server.dev>
   <port.dev>8080</port.dev>
   <server.qa>QA_SERVER</server.qa>
   <port.qa>8091</port.qa>
</properties>
```

Assuming that yout have file `src/main/resources/config.ini` that has all the other stuff but these few params you can "multiply" that file with different environment settings by `ant`'s `copy` & `concat` tasks.

Then configure `maven-antrun-plugin` to run script for writing these files

```
<plugins>
   ...
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.8</version>
      <dependencies>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>ant-contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant-contrib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0b3</version>
            <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                  <groupId>ant</groupId>
                  <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant-nodeps</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
         </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <executions>
         <execution>
            <id>create_file</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <configuration>
               <target>
                  <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"
                     classpathref="maven.compile.classpath" />
                    <for list="qa,dev" param="ENV">
                       <sequential>
                          <copy file="src/main/resources/config.ini"     
                                tofile="target/config_@{ENV}.ini"/>
                          <concat destfile="target/config_@{ENV}.ini" 
                                  append="true"><![CDATA[
SERVER=${server.@{ENV}}
PORT=${port.@{ENV}}]]>
                          </concat>
                       </sequential>
                    </for>
               </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
               <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
         </execution>
      </executions>
   </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: The issue with this approach is that the entire file should be stored in CDATA section, the file is very big. and i have multiple files, I want them outside of this file.

Comment: @user648026 Updated answer to use file that will be concatenated with these params.

Comment: do not follow this, it is a obtuse hack that you will regret, use the `profiles` like they are designed to be used not this hack.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Yes, i agree on that 99%. But it seems to be the only way to get N ini files to get built at one build instead of running N profile builds so I am not sure if this is really a duplicate.